# Google-maps-services-java firebase

Tags: google-maps, firebase

I have a working Java Firebase Admin SDK application. The moment I add google-maps-services to gradle I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.checkNotDeleted(FirebaseApp.java:317)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getOptions(FirebaseApp.java:263)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseDatabase.java:75)
```

The two lines I added to build.gradle are:

```
 compile group: 'com.google.maps', name: 'google-maps-services', version: '0.2.3'
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
```

Question: What am I doing wrong trying to use google-maps-services in a Java Firebase Admin SDK application?

Comment: This looks related: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2380

Answer (score 0):

I filed an issue here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/355

Looks like this will be addressed in a new release.